# Get-ADUser Command Exporting A Partial List of Users

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to export a list of users from my on-premises Active Directory with each user's last logon time. I can get the script to display the information in PowerShell, but I'm running into a problem whereby, when I pipe in an export command, my script exports only the last user on the list of SamAccountNames in a file I'm asking the script to query.

My file is an unformatted list of SamAccountNames in column A.

I've read the official documentation and don't think I understand the cmdlet in enough detail. I've also tried to find similar issues.

This script will iterate through the list of usernames in %file and displays the SamAccountName and LastLogonDate for all users.

```
$file = Get-Content -Path "<<file>>.csv"
foreach ($user in $file)
    {
    Get-ADUser -Server <<DC>> -Identity $user -Properties LastLogonDate | Select-Object SamAccountName, LastLogonDate
    }
```

When I add the Export_Csv command (see below), however, I only get the last entry in the .csv.

```
$file = Get-Content -Path "<<file>>.csv"
foreach ($user in $file)
    {
    Get-ADUser -Server <<DC>> -Identity $user -Properties LastLogonDate | Select-Object SamAccountName, LastLogonDate | Export-Csv "<<file>>.csv" -NoTypeInformation
    }
```

I expected to see all usernames in $file in the exported .csv. However, I get numerous references to the error message "Get-ADUser : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Identity'. The Identity property on the argument is null or empty.
At line:4 char:48" and only the last user in the list.

Based on other reading, I've also tried to add Import-Csv "file.csv" as follows:

```
Import-Csv "<<file>>.csv"
$file = Get-Content -Path "<<file>>.csv"
foreach ($user in $file)
    {
    Get-ADUser -Server <<DC>> -Identity $user -Properties LastLogonDate | Select-Object SamAccountName, LastLogonDate | Export-Csv "<<file>>.csv" -NoTypeInformation
    }
```

Comment: What's the column name of your CSV? Your issue mainly is that you have `Export-Csv` inside the `foreach` loop thus the output file is being overwritten in each loop iteration.

Comment: I don't have a column for the imported .csv? Do I need one and invoke it in the script?

Comment: I dont understand why you have a file with `.csv` extension which has no columns. If it's just a list of SAMs without a column then shouldn't the extension be `.txt` or something else?

Comment: The answer is probably inexperience. I also have a .txt file in the same directory (I was testing it made a difference. I'll try that and taking the export-csv out of the foreach loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're successfully querying each user in the file but the issue is that because `Export-Csv` is inside the `foreach` loop the CSV file is being overwritten in each loop iteration.

Assuming your file is simply a list of `samAccountName`s then you can pipe the output of `Get-Content` directly to `Get-ADUser`, no `foreach` loop needed:

```bash
Get-Content -Path path\to\file.ext |
    Where-Object { -not [string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_) } | # Skip any empty lines
    Get-ADUser -Properties LastLogonDate |
    Select-Object SamAccountName, LastLogonDate |
    Export-Csv path\to\csvexport.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you.

It does return the error "Get-ADUser : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Identity'. The Identity property on the argument is null or empty.", though. Have I done something wrong with the input file?

Comment: You probably have an empty line in the file causing that problem, updated my answer to avoid that problem @OliverBetts-Richards